# HTML 5 and CSS 3, page with 100% width, fixed nav bar and left over space content

Tags: css, html

Currently I'm recoding our website in HTML 5, it is still in HTML 4.1 and runs on tables. SO I want to make it more of this time.

I got everything good so far, the header is over and is showing correctly. How ever I have a problem to get the navigation bar and content working.

THe navbar is on the left side, it has a width of 218px, the content is next to it, and needs to fill up the rest of the page what is left. I have tried different things I got from Google, but it never works.

This is our current website: http://joopvanleeuwen.nl/index.html, and this is my current development site: http://dev.joopvanleeuwen.nl/, we want to keep the design because we like it, our so do our customers.

Is this infact possible with HTML 5 and CSS 3? Ore I'm the first one?

Comment: Technically your current site is running in Quirks mode because it has no doctype, not HTML 4.1.

Comment: Also you shouldn't link to current live versions of the site because as people come to visit this question later they won't be able to see the original problem.  You should put the relevant code in your question or in a jsfiddle.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, I will use them the next time :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a syntax error in your CSS:

```
#container{
  width: 100%
  display: table-row;
}
```

Missing a semi-colon `;` after `width: 100%`.  This... actually probably fixes the problem?

```
#container{
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
```

Comment: That was so stupid of me :# Sadly it didn't fix it. I did a heard refresh.

Comment: Did you change it from `display:table-row;` to `display:table;`?

Comment: Forget that one sorry :#